# Auth0 login popup hide reset password section

Tags: angularjs, auth0

I am using auth0 for login in my apppication. I need to height the reset password section from auth0 login popup how can i hide the Reset password section from auth0 login.

Please suggest. I used  `showForgot: false` to hide reset password but it's not working on my end. Can you please suggest.

Comment: wouldn't `showForgot: true` logically mean that you want to *show* the field, not *hide* it?

Comment: Extremly Sorry showForgot: false .It's my mistake i updated the above code

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention it so I'm assuming you're using Lock latest version. If that's the case, [the documentation indicates](https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/customization#allowforgotpassword-boolean-) that in order to disable the reset password related functionality you need to use:

```
var options = {
  allowForgotPassword: false
};
```

---

If you're not using the latest version than this type of information should be included in the question.